# DebugActiveProcessStop crashes the application being debugged

Tags: c++, c, debugging

I have a debugger attached to an application.

After I'm done getting the information I need, I try to detach the debugger but the application being debugged crashes on `DebugActiveProcessStop()`:

```
int main(void)
{
    HWND window = FindWindow(NULL, L"apptodebug");

    DWORD_PTR pid = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, &pid);

    DWORD address = 0x004F0186; // address of the instruction after the call

    DebugActiveProcess(pid); // PID of target process

    DWORD dwThreadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, &pid);

    CONTEXT ctx = {0};
    ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS | CONTEXT_INTEGER;
    ctx.Dr0 = address;
    ctx.Dr7 = 0x00000001;

    HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwThreadID);

    SetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx); // hThread with enough permissions

    DEBUG_EVENT dbgEvent;

    DWORD edx = 0;
    DWORD ecx = 0;
    int gg = 0;

    while (!gg)
    {
        if (WaitForDebugEvent(&dbgEvent, INFINITE) == 0)
            break;

        if (dbgEvent.dwDebugEventCode == EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT &&
            dbgEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP)
        {
            if (dbgEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress == (LPVOID)address)
            {
                GetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);

                edx = ctx.Edx; // edx get
                ecx = ctx.Ecx; // edx get

                std::cout<<edx<<"\n";
                std::cout<<ecx<<"\n";

                //system("pause");

                gg = 1;
            }
        }

        ContinueDebugEvent(dbgEvent.dwProcessId, dbgEvent.dwThreadId, DBG_CONTINUE);
    }

    DebugActiveProcessStop(pid); // The application I was debugging crashes here.
    DebugSetProcessKillOnExit(false);

    return 0;
}
```

I couldn't find a way to detach the debugger "normally". The application simply "stops working" and closes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are injecting a breakpoint into the process. This will cause an exception when the breakpoint is hit. If you detach the debugger while the breakpoint is active, such an exception will cause the program to crash.

Therefore, disable the breakpoint (set DR7 to 0) first and detach then.

I never did this myself, but something like

```
GetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);
ctx.Dr7 = 0x00000000;
SetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);
ContinueDebugEvent(dbgEvent.dwProcessId, dbgEvent.dwThreadId, DBG_CONTINUE); 
DebugActiveProcessStop(pid);
```

should do.

Comment: I think you may be right. I just managed to get the exception when the app crashes, and it is 0x80000004: Single step.